# Solving Web-service Objects/Instances

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I am getting this error after sending my request:

```
    System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.ApiError]: Unable to process the request as an attempt was made to create an abstract class. (Fault Detail is equal to FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.ApiError).
```

When sending this request:

```
            //MessageBox.Show("Running Add Contact Details Test!");
            CustomerServiceClient customerServiceClient = new CustomerServiceClient();
            AddContactDetailRequest addContactDetailsRequest = new AddContactDetailRequest();
            AddContactDetailResponse addContactDetailsResponse = new AddContactDetailResponse();

            addContactDetailsRequest.ContactDetails = new SITCustomerServiceReference.ContactDetail();

            addContactDetailsRequest.UserName = "username";
            addContactDetailsRequest.Password = "password";
            addContactDetailsRequest.SystemToken = systemToken;
            addContactDetailsRequest.CustomerNumber = "customerNumber";
            addContactDetailsRequest.ContactDetails.SequenceNumber = 1;
```

In SOAP UI the request works fine like this (XML):

```
     <ns:AddContactDetail>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ns:request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:AccessToken/>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:Password>${#Project#password}</data:Password>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:ProcessId/>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:SystemToken>${#Project#systemToken}</data:SystemToken>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <data:UserName>${#Project#username}</data:UserName>
        <!--Optional:-->
     <data:ContactDetails xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:type="data:Phone">
              <data:FinancierContactDetail i:nil="true"/>
               <data:FinancierLocationCode i:nil="true"/>
               <data:FinancierTypeCode i:nil="true"/>
               <data:SequenceNumber>1</data:SequenceNumber>
              <data:Number>${#TestCase#phoneNumber}</data:Number>
              <data:PhoneType>${#TestCase#phoneType}</data:PhoneType>
              <data:UserId i:nil="true"/>
           </data:ContactDetails>
          <!--Optional:-->
        <data:CustomerNumber>00100000000</data:CustomerNumber>
     </ns:request>
  </ns:AddContactDetail>
```

The main problem for me is that I cant find E-Mail/Phone type after typing in addContactDetailsRequest.ContactDetails. and so Obv I expect an error when not sending the actual main contact details.

This is the definition for .ContactDetails:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.ContactDetail ContactDetails {
        get {
            return this.ContactDetailsField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.ContactDetailsField, value) != true)) {
                this.ContactDetailsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ContactDetails");
            }
        }
    }
```

More Definitions if they help:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ContactDetail", Namespace="URL")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.Fax))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.Email))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.Phone))]
public partial class ContactDetail : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Nullable<int> SequenceNumberField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Nullable<int> SequenceNumber {
        get {
            return this.SequenceNumberField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.SequenceNumberField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.SequenceNumberField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SequenceNumber");
            }
        }
    }

     [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Email", Namespace="http://financier.api.welcom.co.uk/2016/10/data")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class Email : FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.ContactDetail {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.DateTime DateDeletedField;

    private string EmailAddressField;

    private FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.EmailType EmailTypeField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string UserIdField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime DateDeleted {
        get {
            return this.DateDeletedField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.DateDeletedField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.DateDeletedField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("DateDeleted");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public string EmailAddress {
        get {
            return this.EmailAddressField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.EmailAddressField, value) != true)) {
                this.EmailAddressField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("EmailAddress");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public FinancierAPITester.SITCustomerServiceReference.EmailType EmailType {
        get {
            return this.EmailTypeField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.EmailTypeField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.EmailTypeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("EmailType");
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I add this Phone/Email/Fax type? So I can actually send the request with the E-Mail/Phone/Fax.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I had to initialise it first then fill in the instances like below:

```
  addContactDetailsRequest.ContactDetails = new SITCustomerServiceReference.Phone();
            SITCustomerServiceReference.Phone phoneContactDetails = new Phone();
            phoneContactDetails.Number = "01772444444";
            phoneContactDetails.PhoneType = SITCustomerServiceReference.PhoneType.Home;
            string currentDateString = "2017/06/11T00:00:00";
            DateTime currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(currentDateString);
            phoneContactDetails.DateDeleted = currentDate;

            addContactDetailsRequest.UserName = "UserName ";
            addContactDetailsRequest.Password = "Password ";
            addContactDetailsRequest.SystemToken = systemToken;
            addContactDetailsRequest.CustomerNumber = "00123456789";
            addContactDetailsRequest.ContactDetails.SequenceNumber = 1;
            addContactDetailsRequest.ContactDetails = phoneContactDetails;
```

Then when it comes to including the email in the request itself just add reference it to the object of which you filled in all the details of after initialising.